# PHP pagina em branco em prod server mas tudo OK em local

Tags: php

Eu tenho este script: e quando o movi para o servidor remoto aparece uma pagina em branco, esta é a unica pag do site que dá isto e não percebo porquê. Em local está tudo ok, não dá erro nenhum e se eu vir a codigo fonte da pag tb não aparece nada. Tudo em branco

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
require_once('conn.php');

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once ('Classes/'.$class.'.php');
});

$database = new DB($db);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pics Upload</title>
        <style>
        * {
            box-sizing:border-box;
            margin: 0;
        }
        div {
            font-size: 0;
        }
        #errors {
            color: red;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        p {
            font-size: 13px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .image {
            width: 33%;
            font-size: 0;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .image img {
            width: 100%;
            border: 2px solid yellow;
        }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id ="wrapper">
<h1>Display all images from Database</h1>
<br>
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<br>
<a href="displayAll.php">Display all images from database</a>
<br>
<a href="mostVoted.php">Display the 3 most voted images</a>
<br>
<a href="imagesFolder.php">Display images from folder</a>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label><br><br>Insert how many random images you want to see<br><input type="text" name="numRandom"></label><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8', 'Portuguese_Brazil');
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

    echo '<br><br>Total Rows (images) in Database: ' .$database->fetchRowCount(). '<br><br>';

    if (isset($_POST['numRandom'])) {
        $numOfRandom = $_POST['numRandom'];
        if ($database->inputRandomCheck($numOfRandom)) {
            $results = $database->selectRandomImage($numOfRandom);

            echo 'Total random images to display: ' .$numOfRandom. '<br><br>';
            echo '<pre>', print_r($results), '</pre>';

            $uppercaseDay = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%A'));

            ?>
            <div id="imgWrapper">
            <?php
            for ($i=0; $i<count($results); $i++) {
                ?>
                <div class="image">
                    <p><?php echo $results[$i]->image_name;
                        echo '<br>' .strftime($uppercaseDay.', %d/%b/%Y - %H:%M:%S', $results[$i]->uploaded); ?>
                    </p>
                    <p>Total votes = <?php echo $results[$i]->vote; ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $results[$i]->link; ?>" target="_blank">
                    <img src="<?php echo $results[$i]->image_path; ?>"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }
        }

        else if (!empty($database->errors())){
            foreach ($database->errors() as $error) {
                echo '<div id="errors">' .$error. '</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        echo 'Total random images to display:<br><br><br>';
    }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A versão do php dos dois servidores é a mesma?

Comment: Sim, aliás esta é a unica página do site em que isto acontece... http://iwanttobesanta.com/picsUpload/ acontece na pag de random images

Comment: O servidor de produção é o mesmo sistema operacional e estrutura de arquivos?

Comment: Bastante pertinente o comentário do @MarceloAymone. lembre-se que na web PHP é quase sempre executado em ambiente *nix que é *case-sensitive* ao passo que a grande maioria dos programadores PHP, programam em Windows que não o é. Também, eu nunca vi passar -1 para error_reporting(). Use um dos valores descritos [no manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: acho que é problema com a conexão do BD e a classe de BD tem algo assim: or die();

Comment: Você tem acesso aos logs de erro do PHP no servidor remoto? Lá eles são sempre gravados, caso a alteração de diretrizes do PHP em tempo de execução (ini_set()) não estejam habilitadas.

Comment: Só para dizer que consegui resolver, sem perceber porquê parece que na parte do "else if (!empty($database->errors)) {..." havia algum tipo de conflito, só retirei o "else" e deixei o "if" e resultou

Comment: @Miguel Qual a versão do php vc estava utilizando? acho que essa [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075534/cant-use-method-return-value-in-write-context) explica o motivo do erro. Poderia fazer o teste trocar a linha `else if (!empty($database->errors())){` por: 
`$erros = $database->errors();
 else if (!empty($erros)){`.

Answer (score 1):

O problema pode estar nesta linha:

```
require_once('conn.php');
```

Ou nesta:

```
require_once ('Classes/'.$class.'.php');
```

Vocês está chamando outro(s) arquivo(s). O que ele(s) faz(em)?

Algo que ajuda a saber onde está o problema é colocar um **echo** com algo para printar antes e depois da linha em que você suspeita haver um erro. Por exemplo:

```
require_once('conn.php');
echo 'Teste';
```

Se imprimir, é porque o erro não está ali.

Outro problema pode estar relacionado à codificação do arquivo. Se ele estiver codificado com UTF-8, verifique se a opção "Incluir Assinatura Unicode (BOM)" não está marcada. Se estiver, isso pode gerar problemas quando se usa comandos como **header**, **session_start()**, etc... para os quais não pode haver qualquer tipo de impressão antes dos mesmos (e o BOM é uma marca impressa no html gerado).

Se após essas verificações o erro não for localizado, por favor, poste o conteúdo completo (arquivo conn.php) para poder lhe ajudar.